# SQL - data input with average value

Tags: sql, sql-server, input

I am currently trying to input the data with SQL statements (I am not very familiar with SQL). I've got a dataset with nulls and I am trying to replace the nulls with the average of whole variable. I was trying such statement (I am using MS SQL):

```
SELECT x1,
       CASE
         WHEN x1 IS NULL THEN AVG(x1)
         ELSE x1
       END AS x1
  FROM dbo.data
```

And it comes back with an error:

> Column 'dbo.data.x1' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I change the AVG value to e.g. 1 - it is working and while I am adding group by it shows only values with no nulls.

It may be a stupid question but is it possible to do such an imput here? As I mentioned I am totally amateur in it and need some help and tips!

Thank you,

Tom

Comment: `THEN (select Avg(dd.x1) from dbo.data dd)`

Comment: You may replace the null values on the script side not on sql side as long as complicated queries could make much load on server

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `avg()` as a *window function* with the window as the entire data set

```
SELECT x1,
       CASE
         WHEN x1 IS NULL THEN AVG(x1) over()
         ELSE x1
       END AS x1
  FROM dbo.data
```

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I wanted. Now when I want to update this variable in whole dataset do I just need to put the update table with that statement?

Comment: That sounds like a different question to the one you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `coalesce()` instead of `case`.  It is more conices:

```
select d.*,
       coalesce(x1, avg(x1) over ()) as imputed_x1
from data d;
```